# Choices Field link to an attribute.Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to link a specific Choices field to an attribute? I've done some research and did not see anything posted.

**Models.py**

```
SIZES_CHOICES = (
            ('Small', 'Small'),
            ('Medium', 'Medium'),
            ('Large', 'Large')
           (

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sizes = models.CharField(choices=SIZES_CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default="Small")
    small_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, (code that will associate it to Small Size))
    medium_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, (code that will associate it to Medium Size))
    large_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, (code that will associate it to Large Size))
```

**Actual Models.py**

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Beverage', 'Beverage'),
    ('Pasta','Pasta'),
    ('Cake','Cake'),
    ('Bakery','Bakery'),
    ('Sandwiches','Sandwiches'),
)

SIZES_CHOICES = (
    ('Short', 'Short'),
    ('Tall', 'Tall'),
    ('Grande', 'Grande'),
    ('Venti', 'Venti')
)

CAKE_CHOICES = (
    ('SLICE','SLICE'),
    ('WHOLE','WHOLE'),
)

def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return 'Items/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.name, filename)

def create_new_ref_number():
      return str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999))

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    sizes = models.CharField(choices=SIZES_CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default="Short")
    cake_size = models.CharField(choices=CAKE_CHOICES, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, default="SLICE")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    beverage_s_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    beverage_t_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    beverage_g_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    beverage_v_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cake_slice_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    cake_whole_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug= models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("featured-food", 
                       kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    
    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
        
    def get_add_to_cart_store_page_url(self):
        return reverse("add-to-cart-store-page", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def get_remove_from_cart_store_page_url(self):
        return reverse("remove-from-cart-store-page", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sizes = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    cake_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True, blank=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item_quantity} of {self.item}"
    
    
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reference_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
                                        null=True, blank=True, 
                                        unique=True, default=create_new_ref_number())
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference_number
```

Kindly check my actual models.py. What I want to accomplish here is to normalized and pass through the value to the views.py. [image]

I added a picture of the template.

Comment: Why do you need those fields if you already have the data in the `sizes` field?

Comment: I am trying to pass it through the radio button. If the customer selected small size, I would like to get the size and the price. Right now, I've done it but I can only get the price value. I am thinking of a way to pass through the price and size to a radio button and get it when the function is called.

Comment: I actually edited my post.

Comment: I see, there are different prices for each size and you want a method to get the correct price depending on the size? Can you give an example where you are using this model?

Comment: Exactly, Let say you order a coffee in Starbucks, and each size has a different price. In my project, I can only pass the value of the price as the Radio button can only handle 1 value per option.

Comment: @Ian: this looks like odd modeling. A model should only be concerned with *storing* data in the database, not with handling data by the user. That is what a form is for. So normally you can make an `Item` that lists the different prices, and then a `Form` where users can pick the size of the `Item` they want.

Comment: I see. I am not actually using a Form for this one as of the moment, but I will try that. I am just requesting to get the value of the selected radio button and pass it through the price attribute. I think I need to refactor my model and add a form for this one.

Comment: @ian You need to normalize your models. Let's start really simple. We will consider that an Item can have multiple sizes. and for each size there's a different price, so there should be a model let's say `Size` which will store the size option, the price and a foreign key to `Item`. Of course in a real world there are many more options so you would need to design properly keeping everything in mind. Currently your schema is not in 3NF (3rd normal form, search about normalization a bit) making things difficult for you.

Comment: Adding something like an `ItemVariant` model may make sense: have a `ForeignKey` to `Item` a name/label and a price. This way you can link orders/choices directly to the variant and your radio inputs for each `Item` can be generated from the variants, the price can then be accessed directly from the linked variant too

Comment: Guyz, can you check my actual models.py.I just updated my post and I really appreciate your help.